# How can I wire an Insteon switch in this situation?

Tags: dimmer-switch

I've been installing Insteon switches around the house, and I've run into a bit of an issue. In our bedroom, we have a switch that controls the fan lights and recessed lights as well as single switches that control each separately.

After removing the switch and installing the switch like I thought it should go, and it not working, I started troubleshooting it. With the switch for the recessed lighting on the wires carrying the load changes. So I tried using both of those wires as the the ones carrying the load, I still couldn't get the lights to work. Below is a picture of the wires.

[image: Master Switch]

Comment: It appears that your new switch requires a neutral, do you have a neutral there? What is the wire identified as line, is it hot, neutral, or switched? With the two hots, are they always hot, is one switched, or are both travelers to a second 3 way switch?

Comment: The Neutral is attached via the white wire. The one identified as line is never hot, so I believed it to be the one that carries the load back to the other switches. The two hots: one is hot when another switch is on, and the other is hot when the other switch is off.

Comment: @cabtex, please explain a bit clearer as to what you had in each spot. I am confused as to what switches were where. What does "Hot 1" & "Hot 2" mean? BTW, I am familiar with Insteon. I've done homes with full Insteon switching and have a bunch in my own home also utilizing the newer hub. The old 2412N Smart-Linc was not working well for me.

Comment: "When the other switch is on" seems to imply your mixing a 3 way switch with an Insteon switch and those are "travelers", not "hot 1 and 2". I don't believe insteon switches work with non-insteon 3 way switches. And "line" in your diagram will confuse electricians, it's most likely your "switched hot."

Comment: After some more research, it's definitely a three way switch. When the breaker is flipped on, and the switch inside the room is off, Hot #1 has voltage running through it, and vise versa when it's off. What I think I have to do is install another insteon switch on where the actual primary switch is. It seems the switch I thought was the primary is the secondary switch. https://bithead942.wordpress.com/2014/06/14/insteon-3-way-switch-alternate-wiring/

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a the 3 way switch? That is are there 2 switches in the house that control the same light? If so, you will have to replace both with insteon's for it to work since they will communicate wirelessly. Assuming it's a 3 way, make sure the switches to the light are turned off, since if they are on, some wires will appear hot when they really are not. Assuming the above photo is with the switches off, you have one wire labelled wire and you mention the line is always cold. You have that backwards. The line should be "hot".

The black wire on insteon is labelled line and that should attach to the two hot wires and the black cold wire (which is actually the traveller) should be capped off and cap off the red load wire coming from the insteon.

The other 3 way switch should have the hot wire attached to the line, and one of the wires should be capped (traveller) and the other should go to the red load of the insteon.

Page 11 of the Insteon instructions illustrates this as well. http://cache.insteon.com/documentation/2477D-en.pdf

Comment: Technically, just the switch with the switch leg needs to be changed to an insteon. Other 3way(s) are just a convenience and can be done at a later date if needed to save money.